# Return Status Code from Business Layer for API

Tags: c#, api

I'm making API framework and in API we send StatusCode along with result, let's say I have this class in Data Layer

```
public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have the logic in Business Layer as follows

```
public class UserManager : IUser
{
    public async Task<User> GetById(string UserId)
    {
        try
        {
            //Logic here
            List<User> users = Data.GetById(UserId);
            
            If(!users.Any())
                throw new Exception("User is not found"); // Status Code 404
            Else
                Return users.First(); // Status Code 200
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Internal Server Error"); // Status Code 500
        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is, in the presentation layer I don't know the status code that should be returned as the business layer don't inform them. Another approach is that I could make a class like this :

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    public object Body { get; set; }
    
    public ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode StatusCode) {
        this.StatusCode = StatusCode;
        this.Body = null;
    }
    
    public ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode StatusCode, object Body) {
        this.StatusCode = StatusCode;
        this.Body = Body;
    }
}
```

And change my business layer to this

```
public class UserManager : IUser
{
    public async Task<ApiResponse> GetById(string UserId)
    {
        try
        {
            //Logic here
            List<User> users = Data.GetById(UserId);
            
            If(!users.Any())
                return new ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            Else
                return new ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, users.First());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't like this approach for a few concerns

- Now all of my business layer need to return ApiResponse, nothing else
- Should I need to process the return data in the presentation layer (ex: I need the UserId for something else), I need to hard cast object into the right type, which in this case "(User)data.Body" and this may lead to future mess

Is there any better approach to return StatusCode to the presentation layer?

Comment: You should throw exceptions from you business layer, and catch them in an ExceptionFilter to turn them into whatever HttpCode is relevant.  Then your API layer is not littered with exception and return value checking.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-filters

Comment: I think this question is opinion-based, which is off-topic here. On the hand I would suggest you to take a look at this project: [OneOf](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) before you introduce a custom `ApiResponse` class.

Comment: Sure thank you Peter. Apparently it's not clear enough to you that I'm asking for a solution and not here for opinion. sure.

Comment: It is opinion-based because both approaches (throwing exceptions, using response object) solve your problem. It is subjective which one should be the preferred one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should throw more specific exceptions from your business layer, and catch them in an [ExceptionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-filters) to turn them into whatever HttpCode is relevant.  Then your API layer is not littered with try/catch/exception handling and return value checking.

```
public class UserManager : IUser
{
  public async Task<User> GetById(string UserId)
  {
        //Logic here
        List<User> users = Data.GetById(UserId);
        
        If(!users.Any())
            throw new UserNotFoundException("User is not found"); // Status Code 404
        Else
            Return users.First(); // Status Code 200
  }
}

public class ApiExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext ec)
    {
       switch(ec.Exception)
       {
           case UserNotFoundException enfe:
               context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
               context.Handled = true;
               break;
           default:
               context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
               break;
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you neil, your approach solved my problem. I managed to make some custom exception and filters and satisfied with it. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your business layer should return HTTP status codes.
It doesn't need to be 'aware' of existence of HTTP.
It only 'knows' about Users, and either returns them or throws errors.

Are you using your `UserManager` as a repository of users within an API controller?

Then interpret the return value of the `UserManager` within your controller, and there you can wrap it with a DTO & htttp status code - if you need to do so.

Comment: Yes, UserManager is my repository. I'm under impression that presentation layer shouldn't contain any logic, but is it a common practice to move the logic to the presentation layer? In my case, the If(s) where I check the list<User>

Comment: If you are only concerned about the status code for exception, then you can move that logic to the IExceptionFilter, as per comment by Neil. That being said, it's not like an API controller cannot contain _any logic_. It does not have to be just a pass-over to business logic. 
The point is that your business logic should not be tied to HTTP (just like its not tied to a specific DB). If you have extra behavior that you need to add that is related to HTTP, like the status code, then you can put that logic in webapi controller (although exception filters are there exactly for that purpose:) )

Comment: I have to agree that business logic should not be tied to anything Http-related. I also have considered to put some logic in my controller as you suggested but if I do it for the status code, I imagine that my controller would have too many logic in it, as it would also contain logics for other status codes. Many thanks to your input, I'm currently clarifying with Neil for his solution.